# Decorative metal plates on finish lumber

Tags: trim

I am looking for a name of a product. It is thin decorative metal plates that are usually engraved and nailed to things like doors or other finish lumber. 100% decoration, no functional utility whatsoever. What are those called?

Comment: "Finish lumber" isn't really a thing, as lumber is simply wood boards or sheet goods. Maybe you mean "millwork". Could you post a photo? I don't consider the tags you describe to be _decorative_, so I'm not sure I understand correctly.

Comment: Visible lumber, as opposed to structural like SPF 2x4 inside wall

Comment: Are you asking about metal plates that are on the edges of walls ? These are nail plates  to protect the wires from nails and or screws if the cables are less than 1-1/4” away required by the NEC code for many decades.

Comment: It sounds like tin tiles (ceiling or backsplash). Or "pie safe tins" if you want something smaller.

Comment: No Ed, it's purely decorative.

Comment: escutcheon plates have a minor function, but some are similar to the description.